# Adding large number of users to a group in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I have a list of strings which I use to keep a list of more than 6000 users' `nativeGUID`.

I use Linq to convert them to an array of strings in the format of `<GUID=nativeGUID>` and then use `DirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].AddRange()` to to add them to my group in Active Directory.

When I call `DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()` to commit changes to AD it takes around 20 minutes to complete.

Is there any faster way to add large amount of users to a group using their `nativeGUID`?

Comment: Consider running some tests wherein the group is removed, then added with the 6000 members. This might increase the performance to an acceptable level.

Comment: try using a Parallel.ForEach on the array of GUIDs calling commit in each iteration? Also note that the .net framework has undoutedly changed since this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell:

```
Import-Module "Ad*";
Add-AdGroupMember -Identity GROUP-GUID -Members "GUID, GUID, GUID";
```

You can also replace the Members value with an array of GUIDs or with an array of user objects.

Comment: How does this improve performance? The important thing to note about your answer is that now you are offloading the required processing to a totally separate process which will make it harder to monitor for errors and respond to them.